# How to install sqlcmd on windows core

Tags: windows, shell

I have inherited a sick WSUS server running on MS Windows core (i.e. no desktop). The CPU is maxed out by the sqlserv.exe process. This appears to be the embedded version rather than a full featured install of MSSQLserver. Disabling the ASUS service causes the CPU usage to drop from a saturated 100% to a variable 1-2%. I have run the code to decline the superceded patches but this has not resolved the problem. I see that a regular maintenance schedule includes rebuilding the indexes in the database. To that end I have downloaded the SQL script and [sqlcmd](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53591).

However when I try to to install MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi (`msiexec -i MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi` via powershell remote session) I get returned to the command prompt after a short pause but the program is not installed.

Can aynone advise how to get this installed?

Answer (score 0):

The prompt returns because the powershell remote session can't show you the setup UI.

However, you can connect to Windows Server Core using RDP and start the installation from the command line you'll get after logging in.

On the other hand, I recommend you to install sqlcmd on your computer/management workstation and use it remotely: `sqlcmd -S ComputerA\instanceB`

More details about sqlcmd: [Connect to the Database Engine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-connect-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: "...install sqlcmd on your computer..." but I was under the impression that the embedded SQL Server (compared with the standalone server) only supported local named pipes. I'll check netstat when I'm back on the server.

Comment: "...connect to Windows Server Core using RDP" while I get an RDP connection - that's all. No shell. No cursor. Just a black screen :(